# Using a DataServiceContext with custom annotations

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, wcf-data-services

When using the an instance of the DataServiceContext class to materialise objects from an odata endpoint where the endpoint exposes some [custom annotations](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/cs01/odata-json-format-v4.0-cs01.html#_Instance_Annotations), how does one get hold of the annotations data. I can't see any obvious extensibility points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom annotations aren't exposed as a first-class concept on the DataServiceContext, but you can access them by hooking into the client response processing pipeline. This code will run after every entity is finished being read:

```
context.Configurations.ResponsePipeline.OnEntryEnded(
    entryArgs => DoSomething(entryArgs.Entry.InstanceAnnotations));
```

Internally, the WCF Data Services Client uses a lower-level library called ODataLib (aka Microsoft.Data.OData on NuGet). The response and request pipelines allow you to dip into that lower level to get extra information when you need it, but you still get all the conveniences of using the full-fledged WCF Data Services client library. The classes like ODataEntry, ODataFeed, etc. that you work with on the processing pipelines are all part of the ODataLib API.

Comment: Ok great thanks for the reply. I guess this implies that the context is  not thread safe. Is the construction and initialisation of the context costly, if so should i implement an object pool perhaps.

Comment: Correct, the context object is not thread safe. Instantiation/configuration isn't very expensive for the DataServiceContext class, so I think you'll be fine creating a new one each time.

Comment: I have found that when deserializing an ODataCollectionValue of ODataComplexValue it fails with a rather strange message: 
A complex property with an 'odata.type' property annotation was found. Complex properties must not have the 'odata.type' property annotation, instead the 'odata.type' should be specified as an instance annotation in the complex value.

Comment: This means the payload had something like "MyProperty@odata.type" instead of "MyProperty:{odata.type=...}" Sorry, my syntax is messy here.. I think this might be easier as a separate question. (Unless this is an error that only happens with the response pipeline?)